# bool(true) message appears when user is not logged in on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website with wp-event manager plugin and when is user is not logged in, it shows bool(true) message on top of my event submit form. I have test it in local and the message says

```
"C:\wamp64\www\testing\wp-content\plugins\wp-event-manager\wp-event-manager-template.php:393:boolean false"
```

The code ate that line is:

```
390    $generate_username_from_email      = event_manager_generate_username_from_email();
391    $use_standard_password_setup_email = event_manager_use_standard_password_setup_email();
392    $account_required  = event_manager_user_requires_account();
393    var_dump($use_standard_password_setup_email);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove this line `var_dump($use_standard_password_setup_email);`